# Android ScrollView vertical scrollbars on both sides

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

how can I show scrollbar vertical tracks at both sides of a view. I've tried nesting scrollbars and making one left and the other right but it does not show like the attached image
[image]
Thanks

Comment: What result are you getting? Have you tried `scrollIndicators` in ScrollView. But this is only for API >= 23.

Comment: scrollIndicators shows only either sides not both sides